# Sum of two standard variables with joint bivariate distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, correlation

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ have standard normal distribution and let $(X_1,X_2)$ have a joint bivariate normal distribution.

Can anyone explain why: $X_1+X_2=\sqrt{2+2\rho}Z$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $\rho$ is the correlation coefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the fact that any linear combination of jointly normal random variables is a normal random variable, regardless of independence. For a proof, see the answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19948/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-sum-of-non-i-i-d-gaussian-variates).

As shown in the [second answer to this linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19953/46427), by characteristic functions, the variance of $Y = X_1+X_2$ is shown to be 
$$\sigma^2_Y = \sigma^2_{X_1} + \sigma^2_{X_2} + 2\text{Cov}(X_1, X_2) = \sigma^2_{X_1} + \sigma^2_{X_2} + 2\rho\sigma_{X_1}\sigma_{X_2} = 2 + 2\rho$$
using the formula $\sigma^2_Z=\Sigma_{11}+\Sigma_{22}+2\Sigma_{21}$ given in the answer. Furthermore, it is trivial to see that $\mathbb{E}[X_1 + X_2] = 0$. So, $Y$ follows a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $2 + 2\rho$; hence, there exists a $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ such that
$$Z = \dfrac{Y}{\sqrt{2+2\rho}}$$
and the result follows.